# Is it possible to disable the function window.open in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get rid of the window.open function. Is it somehow possible to override or deactivate this function?

I fact a want a browser in which the function window.open is not implemented at all. And I want a browser which is not able to load any resource which comes from another host than that one typed into address bar. (I know that many pages would not work any more in that browser.) But I know I will not get.

Sometime I visit a page that uses window.open by onclick for advertisement. I’m not against advertisement, but against unwanted pop-ups.

I want to inject those pages with my own JS to disable open().

Comment: “Disable” for whom and in what context?

Comment: There is no reliable way to do that.